# extracting name from nested data to use as plot label in purrr:map( ~ggplot call

Tags: r, ggplot2, purrr

I am trying to do some exploratory data analysis using tidyverse.  I have a large and complex dataset, but the important parts boil down to something similar to this:

```
my_df <- data.frame(Expt = rep(c("Expt1", "Expt2", "Expt3", "Expt4"), each = 96),
                  ExpType = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 192),
                  Treatment = c(rep("T1", 192), rep("T2", 144), rep("T1", 48)),
                  Subject = c(rep(c("S01", "S02", "S03", "S04", "S05", "S06", "S07", "S08"), 24), rep("S01", 96), rep("S06", 96)),
                  xvar = as.factor(rep(rep(c(10, 5, 2.5, 1.25, 0.6, 0.3, 0.16, 0.08, 0.04, 0.02, 0, "NA"), each = 8),  4)),
                  yvar = runif(384))
```

(Expt is a unique but uninformative identifier for each individual experiment.  Each Expt always has only one ExpType, but may include one or multiple levels of Treatment and Subject.)

I'm grouping my data by ExpType, Treatment, Subject, and Expt, then making graphs.  Thus, I'm making a ton of graphs, and it would make my life **much** easier if the graphs had informative titles.

I can group the data and make graphs of everything, like so:

```
my_df2 <- my_df %>%
group_by(ExpType, Treatment, Expt) %>% 
nest() %>%

mutate(plots1 = map(
  .x = data,
  ~ggplot(data = .x, aes(x=as.factor(xvar), y = yvar)) + # 
    theme_classic() + theme(legend.key.width = unit(2, "lines"), legend.justification = c(1, 1), legend.position = c(1, 1)) +
    geom_smooth(method = "loess", se = FALSE, aes(group=Subject, color=Subject, linetype = Subject))+ 
    geom_point(aes(fill = Subject), size = 2.5) 
))


walk(.x = my_df2$plots1,  ~print(.x))
```

What I can't figure out how to do is add a title to each plot to tell me what it is.  I've tried making a unique identifier that includes all the relevant information:

```
my_df3 <- my_df %>%
  mutate(FullID = paste0(my_df$ExpType, "_", my_df$Treatment, "_", my_df$Expt)) %>%   
  group_by(ExpType, Treatment, Expt) %>% 
  nest() %>%
  arrange(ExpType, Treatment)
```

And I can get the FullIDs back out again:

```
#  Either of these will successfully extract a list of FullIDs
map(my_df3$data, "FullID")

my_df3$data %>% 
  map("FullID")
```

What I can't figure out how to do is to get down that extra level of nesting in the map(~ggplot call to use FullID as a plot title, using something like:

```
my_df3 <- my_df3 %>%  
  mutate(plots2 = map2(
    .x = data, 
    .y = map_chr(data$FullID),
    ~ggplot(.x, aes(x=xvar, y = yvar)) + # 
      theme_classic() + theme(legend.key.width = unit(2, "lines"), legend.justification = c(1, 1), legend.position = c(1, 1)) +

      geom_smooth(method = "loess", se = FALSE, aes(group=Subject, color=Subject, linetype = Subject))+ 
      geom_point(aes(fill=Subject, shape = Subject), size = 2.5) + 
      labs(title = unique(.y))
  ))
```

I know there must be a way to do it, and I just don't get the syntax.  Any suggestions?

Comment: The issue is `map_chr(data$FullID)`

Comment: I couldn't find the 'Strain' column in your data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FullID` can also be created with `unite` (Note that we don't need `.$` inside the `dplyr` functions).  After the `nest/arrange`,  in the OP's code, `map2` was used with one of the input arguments as `map_chr(data$FullID)`.  For `map` to works, it needs a function (`.f`) to be applied, which is not present.  Also, as we are extracting the info from one of the columns in the `list` column 'data'. we don't need a `map2`, but a single `map` and later can extract the column info in `labs`

```
my_df2 <- my_df %>% 
             unite(FullID, ExpType, Treatment,  Expt, sep="_", remove = FALSE) %>% 
             group_by(ExpType, Treatment, Expt) %>%
             nest %>% 
             arrange(ExpType, Treatment) %>%
             mutate(plots = map(data, ~ 
                  ggplot(.x, aes(x=xvar, y = yvar))   + 
                     theme_classic() + 
                     theme(legend.key.width = unit(2, "lines"), 
                       legend.justification = c(1, 1), legend.position = c(1, 1)) + 
                     geom_smooth(method = "loess", se = FALSE, 
                        aes(group=Subject, color=Subject, linetype = Subject))+ 
                     geom_point(aes(fill=Subject, shape = Subject), size = 2.5) +
                     labs(title =  first(.x$FullID))))
```

-checking

```
my_df2$plots[[1]]
```

[image]